# C++ transform not declared in scope only occurs on server

Tags: c++, linux

I've seen a lot of these but none of them seem to correspond to my problem. This program runs locally fine but on the server it needs to run on I run into an error.

project1.cpp: In function ‘void insertwords(char*)’:
project1.cpp:54:65: error: ‘transform’ was not declared in this scope
   transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);

the relevant code:

```
void insertwords(char *filename) {
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(filename);
        if(fin.fail())
            {
            cerr << "File opening failed. Exiting program.\n";
            exit (-1);
            }
    string word;
    int count = 0;
    while (!fin.eof() ) {
        word.clear();
        fin >> word;
        transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);
        for (int i = 0, len = word.size(); i < len; i++)
        {
            if(ispunct(word[i]))
            word.erase(i--, 1);
            len = word.size();
        }
        if(!word.empty()) {
            insert_word(word);
            ++count;
                }
        }


    cout << "The number of words found in the file was " << count << "\n";
    fin.close();
}
```

Includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;
```

I know using namespace std; is bad practice but I was told to for the project

Comment: Did you include [`<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to `#include <algorithm>` which is the header where [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) comes from.

As to why it would compile on one machine and not another, my guess would be that one of your other headers (e.g. `<string>`) includes `<algorithm>` in one of the compiler implementations so you got lucky, but not for the other compiler.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have solved it. Any idea why it runs locally on my Mac without algorithm included?

Comment: @JohnSmith I had the same problem. Its running well on mac but not on the codeforces online IDE.